# Are Tacx turbo trainer frames the same across models?

Tags: maintenance, parts, turbo-trainer

All of Tacx' wheel-on turbo trainers look like they have the same frames (looking at current rather than older models). Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to upgrade from say a Flow to a Vortex, Bushido, or Genius simply by swapping out the resistance unit.